# Inverse of projection map is continuous

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Suppose $Q$ is a topological space and $Q/\sim$ the corresponding quotient space. Let $\pi: Q \rightarrow Q/\sim$ denote the projection map, mapping each $q \in Q$ to the corresponding equivalence class $[q] \in Q/\sim$.

I had initially thought that this map is open (or equivalently, that its inverse is continuous) by definition. A quick proof is suppose $U \subset Q/\sim$ is open. Then $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is open by definition, as the quotient topology is defined by taking all sets of the form $\pi(V)$ to be open where $V$ is in the topology of $Q$.

However based on a few questions I have read on here it seems that the inverse of the projection map is not necessarily continuous. Where does my proof fail? Also, am I mistaken to take a continuous inverse to be the same as an open map?

If I had to guess, perhaps my assumption that the quotient topology is generated by all the open sets via the projection map is incorrect? In other words, the topology on $Q/\sim$ is generated by all sets of the form $\pi(U)$, where $U$ is in the topology of $Q$. If so, what is the difference from this approach and that of only considering sets of the form $\pi^{-1}(U)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "proof" simply uses the definition of continuity for the map $\pi$. That is, you've simply shown why $\pi$ is continuous, not its inverse. However, don't confuse the notation for $\pi^{-1}(U)$, which stands for the pre-image of $U$ under $p$, for the inverse of a function. The notation $\pi^{-1}$ one sees in the definition of continuity always means the pre-image - it's not, in general, a function. We are not necessarily assuming existence of inverses in the definition of contunity. In fact, we can even say that in general, the projection map does not have an inverse. As an example, we can define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by letting $(x,y) \sim (x',y')$ iff $y = y'$. The map $p: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 / \sim$ defined by $p(x,y) = [y]$ will not have an inverse $g: \mathbb{R}^2 / \sim \to \mathbb{R}^2$. For instance, what would $g([2])$ be? It could be $(1,2)$. But it could just as likely be $(0,2)$ or $(-100, 2)$. The problem is that the projection map $p$ is not necessarily injective.

Now, if we assume the projection map is bijective (technically only injectivity is necessary since the projection map is surjective, by definition), we can ask whether or not your characterization would be correct. In fact, the answer is yes. I'll state this formally:

> **Proposition:** Let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on a topological space $Q$, and suppose the projection map $p: Q \to Q / \sim$ given by $p(x) = [x]$ is injective. Then, the inverse of $p$, which we shall denote by $g: Q / \sim \to Q$, is continuous iff $p$ is open.

**Proof**: Let $g: Q / \sim \to Q$ be the inverse of the projection map $p: Q \to Q / \sim$, and assume $p$ is open. Now, let $U \subset Q$ be an open set. We must show $g^{-1}(U)$ is open. But thanks to the fact $p$ is bijective, we know that $g^{-1}(U) = p(U)$. As $p$ was an open map, by assumption, we conclude $p(U)$ is open. Thus, $g^{-1}(U)$ is open implying that the inverse function $g$ is continuous. To prove the converse, suppose that $g$ is continuous, and let $U \subset Q$ be open. By the bijectivity of $p$, we have $p(U) = g^{-1}(U)$, and as $g$ was continuous by assumption, $g^{-1}(U)$ is open $\implies p(U)$ is open. Thus, $p$ is an open map.

Comment: Ah I see, so to prove that the inverse function $\pi^{-1}$ is continuous, or equivalently that that $\pi$ is an open map, we first have to prove that $\pi^{-1}$ is a function, and then afterwards show that $(x^{-1})^{-1}(V) = x(V)$ is open for any open set $V$?

Comment: I suppose part of what is bothering me is that it seems $\pi$ should be an open map straight from the definition of a quotient space. That is, the topology of $Q/\sim$ is generated by looking at all sets of the form $\pi(U)$ for $U$ open in $Q$.

Comment: I've included more details to my answer to showcase when your intuitions would be correct.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. I'm beginning to realize my misunderstandings probably have to do with how the quotient topology itself is generated, but to not ask too many questions at once I have opened a separate question for that.

Comment: Also, imposing $\pi$ to be injective would result in some sort of "trivial" quotient, right?

Comment: @CBBAM That would definitely be true. Often times, it's interesting to see when $Q$ and $Q / \sim$ result in different topological spaces. The example with $\mathbb{R}^2$ that I gave in my answer has a nice result: $\mathbb{R}^2 / \sim$ as given is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. However, imposing $\pi$ to be injective would mean that $Q$ and $Q / \sim$ would always be homeomorphic no matter what spaces $Q$ or what equivalence relation $\sim$ you're looking at. That is, there would be no point in studying the quotient space $Q / \sim$ since it would always be the same, topologically, to $Q$

Comment: Got it, I think I understand now. Thank you for your help and your patience!